# how to find by subdocument and document and the update is pushing a subdocument

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

so i have this models

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: [{type: String, required: true, unique: true}],
    comments: [{
        id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
        user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'},
        comments: {type: String},
        like: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}],
        time: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    }],
    caption: {type: String},
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: true},
    like: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}],
    status: {type: Number,default: 0}
}, {timestamps: true});
```

what i'm trying to do is to push comments' like based on comments' id
i've try

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id:req.body.postid,
            'comments.id':req.body.id
        }, {
            $push :{
                "comments.$.like" : res.userdata.id
            }
        }, {}, err => {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).json({
                    err: err
                })
            }else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: "success",
                });
            }
        });
```

but it doesn't work.. and the worse is this is the document when i find the post

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d6d4754599d8b06c01b1894"),
    "image" : [
            "2019-09-02T16-46-11.835Z123 - Copy.jpg",
            "2019-09-02T16-46-11.892Z123.jpg",
            "2019-09-02T16-46-11.938Z8358-dragon-1680x1050-digital-art-wallpaper - Copy.jpg",
            "2019-09-02T16-46-11.943Z8358-dragon-1680x1050-digital-art-wallpaper.jpg",
            "2019-09-02T16-46-11.949Zasd.jpg",
            "2019-09-02T16-46-11.979Zasd1.jpg",
            "2019-09-02T16-46-11.991Zwallpaper2you_567134.jpg"
    ],
    "like" : [ ],
    "status" : 0,
    "caption" : "asd",
    "user" : ObjectId("5d6c8d934a401d3748ef0c3e"),
    "comments" : [
            {
                    "like" : [ ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d476f599d8b06c01b189a"),
                    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-02T16:46:39.499Z")
            }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-09-02T16:46:12.034Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-09-02T16:46:39.498Z"),
    "__v" : 0
```

idk why user and comments subdocuments is deleted and even the like field doesn't push

note: my mongoose dependencies `"mongoose": "^5.6.4",`

any suggestion?
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can use by the following method ,

```
Post.findOne({_id:req.body.postid,
            'comments.id':req.body.id })
            .exec((err , foundObject)=>{
               if(err){
                   console.log(err);
               }else{
                 console.log("Object ===>" . object);
                 object.comments.push( res.userdata.id);
                 object.save(function (err) {
                   if(err) {
                    console.error('ERROR!');
                   }
                 }); 
               }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the type of `req.body.postid`, `res.userdata.id` and `req.body.id` is ObjectId? Try this way

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: ObjectId(req.body.postid),
        comments.id: ObjectId(req.body.id)
    }, 
    {
        $push: {
            comments.like: ObjectId(res.userdata.id)
        }
    }, {}, err => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                err: err
            })
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "success",
            });
        }
    }
);
```